# Есть ли для VS Code расширение, которое предлагает название таблиц и колонок автоматически, при работе с командами(select, delete и т.д.) в php файле?

Tags: php, mysql, visual-studio-code, phpstorm

Есть ли для VS Code расширение, которое предлагает название таблиц и колонок автоматически, при работе с командами MySQl (select, delete и т.д.) в php файле, как это работает в PhpStorm?
Если есть, подскажите название пожалуйста.

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/tools/visual-studio-code/sql-server-develop-use-vscode?view=sql-server-ver15

**mssql** Есть такое вот расширение. Ещё можно посмотреть в поиске расширений, по комментам, рейтингу

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]